# curl command line POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I'm trying to simulate a POST to my simple Rails scaffold web service. The files created by the scaffold have not been changed. When I POST data from the website form, a record is created correctly.

When I attempt to POST with curl, a record is created in the database, but it has NULL values in the fields, except for 'updated_at' and 'created_at'. I'm new to command line curl so I may not be doing it correctly.

```
curl -d "name=Gazoo&friend=Rubble" localhost:3000/flintstones
```

I get back this from WEBrick:

> Started POST "/flintstones" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Apr 28 18:04:47 -0600 2011  Processing by FlintstonesController#create as  Parameters: {"name"=>"Gazoo", "friend"=>"Rubble"}  AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "flintstones" ("name", "friend", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2011-04-29 00:04:47.779902', '2011-04-29 00:04:47.779902')  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/flintstones/4

After a GET for the json

> curl localhost:3000/flintstones.json

I receive:

[{"flintstone:{"name":null,"created_at":"2011-04-29T00:09:58Z","updated_at":"2011-04-29T00:09:58Z","id":4,"friend":null}}]

Why do I get null in my fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems that the url parameters aren't getting passed to the sql insert and NULLs are getting inserted instead.

Comment: That's correct Dan. And my question is why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've googled a bit and every example of using curl with a rails web service shows the parameters passed in the format

`object[paramName]=paramValue`

as well as one `-d` set for each parameter which would make your CURL statement look like

`curl -d "flintstone[name]=Gazoo" -d "flintstone[friend]=Rubble" localhost:3000/flintstones`

Here are the sources I'm referencing:

- [How to Use cURL to Test RESTful
  Rails](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/08/04/how-to-use-curl-to-test-restful-rails/)
- [Using cURL to test RESTful
  Rails Web Services](http://derek.broox.com/using-curl-to-test-restful-rails-web-services/)

Comment: Thank you Jeff. I had seen the second source you cited, which wasn't helpful. The first one, which I hadn't seen, is helpful. Your solution above did the trick. Now on to using ASIHttpFormRequest or RestKIT for my trial iOS app.

Comment: Goes to show how good formatting can make a blog post much more productive to readers.

Comment: In case you need authentification as well, look here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/curling-with-rails-authenticity-token. Several parameters can also be combined using &

Answer (score 3):

Rails (by default) doesn't look for a post body in the way provided, "`name=Gazoo&friend=Rubble`". It looks for this scheme - given your model is Flintstones and your fields are name and friend - "`Flintstone[name]=Gazoo&Flintstone[friend]=Rubble`". This is rail's DSL for post body from a form post.