# testing rails grape API with curl, params array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl, ruby-grape

I am manually testing my rails application grape API using curl. I would like to send a [1,2,3] array as a request query parameter for to to be accesible like:

```
p params[:tickets_ids]
=> [1,2,3]
```

I only found clues how to send something what is [interpreted as hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826690/curl-command-line-post) .

I will be grateful for a clue how to post an array using curl.

Comment: You can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312930/passing-array-of-parameters-through-get-in-rails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for the clue. The answer is to encode query like this:

```
?&tickets_ids[]=1&tickets_ids[]=2&tickets_ids[]=3
```

Results in:

```
p params[:tickets_ids]
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: How would I go about posting an array of arrays? in terms of a curl call?