# Submitting an array of arrays to grape rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, curl, ruby-grape

managed to submit a simple array to my grape api following this tip

[testing rails grape API with curl, params array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314017/testing-rails-grape-api-with-curl-params-array)

Building a simple workout tracker that generates a graph at the end, through this array of workouts, which should be passed with their keys I guess.

But since what i'm trying to do is a 2D array, i have this output, the type is set to Array[Array], this is the call that i'm currently using

```
 curl --data 'workouts_array[]=1&workouts_array[]=2&workouts_array[]=3' http://localhost:3000/api/v1/workouts/workout.json
```

And it returns

```
{
"workouts_array": [
    [
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "2"
    ],
    [
      "3"
    ]
  ]
}
```

But i wish to pass something like workouts_array[]=[1][2][3]&workouts_array[]=[4][5][6]

so it returns

```
{
"workouts_array": [
    [
      "time": "1", "distance": "2",  "calories": "3",
    ],
    [
      "time": "4", "distance": "5",  "calories": "6",
    ]
  ]
}
```

Thank you for any help, I guess it's just my poor way of using curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I correctly understood you but
for your case you can use this query 
`workouts_array[0]=1&workouts_array[0]=2&workouts_array[0]=3
&workouts_array[1]=4&workouts_array[1]=5&workouts_array[1]=6`

it should return smth similar to:

```
[
  [
   "1",
   "2",
   "3"
  ],
  [
   "1",
   "2",
   "3"
  ]
]
```

this is array of arrays.

you says you set the type `Array[Array]` but wanna see the array of hashes. it's kinda different.

BTW, I prefer use JSON payload for those things.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. I also should switch to JSON payload but it's still quite a confusion for me, cheers.